# MockWebServer enqueue by path condition?

Tags: mocking, retrofit2, okhttp, mockwebserver

I'm using `MockWebServer` from okhttp3 to test my webclient against a mocked external webserver.

I want to configure the mock so that responses are returned *conditional by path*.

Like pseudocode:

```
mockWebServer.expectPath("/products")
             .enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody(..))
             .expectPath("/items")
             .enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody(..));
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible. I had a similar problem and I ended up writing a small open source Android library on top of MockWebServer to make this as simple as possible: **[Mockinizer](https://github.com/donfuxx/Mockinizer)**

In your case your OkHttpClient setup would look something like this:

```
val mocks: Map<RequestFilter, MockResponse> = mapOf(

    RequestFilter("/products") to MockResponse().apply {
        setBody("..")
    },

    RequestFilter("/items") to MockResponse().apply {
        setBody("..")
    }

)

OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        .mockinize(mocks) // <-- just plug in your custom mocks here
        .build()
```

You just plug in the mocks into the OkHttpClient. You don't have to bother with setting up mockWebServer yourself. Mockinizer does that automatically for you ;-)